# Mouse back/forward buttons in FreeBSD under VMWare Workstation

Tags: xorg, vmware-workstation, freebsd

- VMWare Workstation 7.1.4
- Host: Windows 7 (laptop with touchpad).
- Guest: FreeBSD 8.2-STABLE (yesterday's)
- vmmouse driver: 12.6.9_1 (from ports)

The problem: xev doesn't see mouse back/forward buttons (physically connected to laptop through usb). Wheel is working okay (i.e. 4 & 5 buttons work). FreeBSD thinks that the mouse is ps/2, because there are no `/dev/ums*` devices.

`/etc/rc.conf`:

```
moused_type=auto
moused_enable=YES
moused_flags="-r high"
```

`/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver "vmmouse"
    Option "Protocol" "auto"
    Option "Device" "/dev/sysmouse"
    Option "Buttons" "7"
EndSection
```

I don't want to use vmware `usb.generic.allowHID` option to connect the mouse to virtual FreeBSD through usb because I need that mouse in the host & in the guest at the same time.

**Is there any hint how to force vmware or moused or xorg to recognize 6 & 7 button on the "ps/2" mouse?**

(**It is possible somehow theoretically**, because my Windows XP guest (with vmware tools installed) uses vmware ps/2 mouse driver (not the usb one, I checked) and back/forward buttons work fine there.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load the USB mouse driver in `/boot/loader.conf`:

```
ums_load="YES"
```